# D3.js table lookup not working on one site ... works on localhost site

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am developing a site on localhost and am now testing it on a shared host.
The site works correctly on localhost but the a colour lookup function doesn't. Both sites are Drupal but not identically configured. But I have no idea where to start looking. 
In the localhost version: console.log("Colour " + categoryColour [bottom.field_category]); // displays "blue" and in the web version it is undefined

```
var imageAttributes = {height:32, width:32, x:-16, y:-16};
console.log(categoryColour ["volunteer"]); // displays "blue"
var imageAttributes = {height:32, width:32, x:-16, y:-16};
d3.json("../sites/default/d3_files/json/members.json?nocache=" + (new Date()).getTime(),function(error,data){
var bottom=data.organizations.map(function(data) {
  return data.member;
});
 circles.selectAll("circle")
 .data(bottom)
 .enter()
 .append("circle")
 .attr("cx", 0)
 .attr("cy", 0)
 .attr("r", 16)
 .style("fill", function(bottom) { 
      console.log("Category "+[bottom.field_category]); // displays "volunteer"
      console.log("Colour " + categoryColour [bottom.field_category]); // displays "undefined"
      return categoryColour [bottom.field_category]
      })
 .style("stroke", function(bottom) { 
      return categoryColour [bottom.field_category]
      })     
   .style("stroke-width", 0.25)
 .attr("transform",function(bottom){
    return"translate("+projection([bottom.field_lng,bottom.field_lat])+")"; // adjust location
}) // end transform attr
```

Comment: what is "categoryColour". It appears to be a js array, but your code doesn't appear to define it. I suspect perhaps there is another js file/script that is not included in this post

Comment: I didn't include it because the code is identical ... obviously I should have: <script>var categoryColour = {
    "volunteer": "blue",
    "organization": "green",
    "air": "transparent"
  };
</script>

Comment: Very much suggest a jsfiddle to play with if possible. Suspect that the data returned by "../sites...." may be at play. Perhaps the values returned don't work as keys in that associative array.

Comment: If I knew how to use jsfiddle properly (other than to upload code) I would. But you are right. I thought that the members.json file was identical but I was wrong. I did not make any changes that I thought were significant but obviously I must have. Thanks.

Comment: That was the problem. I had used a Drupal module/view to generate the json field but had not noticed that the categories were Capitalized. Thanks for helping me to see that.

Comment: Would you mind posting that as an answer for future reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was that I had used a Drupal module/view to generate the json field but had not noticed that the categories were Capitalized. When I lowercased them it worked.